# why some time-wait connection can be reused and some others cannot

Tags: go, connection

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    reuse "github.com/libp2p/go-reuseport"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := reuse.Dial("a.b.c.d:port1", "d.e.f.g:port2")
    fmt.Println(conn, err)
}
```

above is the code

this dial will set sock SO_REUSEADDR,but what I have encounting is
sometime I can do `reuse.Dial("a.b.c.d:port1","d.e.f.g:port2")` without error,and sometime this return error with `cannot assign requested address`,is the kernel use some algorithm to let this happen

ps: kernel version 2.6.32-431

the picture below show what I state, sometime ok,sometime traceback
[image]

Comment: Note that you don't need a special package for `SO_REUSEADDR`, that is set by default when Go creates a socket.

Comment: @JimB the option set only in passvie request, the active  cannot, this will be added in go1.11 according to golang github issue. maybe I'm not make myself clear. I will close the conn when dial success,then make another request with this tuple again, finally this will lead to two different result，one with err and another one will get conn successfully

Comment: Ok. Socket error 99 is EADDRNOTAVAIL, and I'm guessing that's from `connect`, not bind. If it really is a TIME_WAIT issue, have you tried setting ` tcp_tw_reuse`? I think the real question here is why would you want to do this in the first place? If you must use a specific local and remote port combination, and are making the requests frequently enough that this is an issue, why are you closing the connection?